# what is the cost of Math.sqrt vs Math.sin JS

Tags: javascript

I'm making several calculations that can be done with square roots or with trigo-1 functions (acos, asin, atan).
since I'll be using them several times and not all browsers are fast I need to know which function is more "expensive" to use, Math.sqrt() or Math.asin()/Math.acos()/Math.atan()

tnx.

Comment: Try using jsperf.com with each of those methods listed above. However, I wouldn't worry too much about the JS cost of running those methods, and more of which method mathematically is more concise and efficient.

Comment: This question is very unclear.I would certainly look to avoid language like "several times" and "not all browsers are fast". It is impossible to know exactly what you mean, but just about any built in operator or method can be "used several times" by all browsers without any problems at all.

Comment: It's implementation-dependent. ECMAScript doesn't specify any algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try for yourself. I have not tried it, but feel free to run a script like this:

```
var largeNumber = 1000;

// first method
start = performance.now();

for (var i = 1; i < largeNumber ; i++) {
    Math.sqrt(i);
}

end = performance.now();

diff = end - start;
console.log(diff);

// second method
start2 = performance.now();

for (var i = 1; i < largeNumber ; i++) {
    Math.asin(i)/Math.acos(i)/Math.atan(i);
}

end2 = performance.now();

diff2 = end2 - start2;
console.log(diff2);
```

If the difference is not significant, increase the value of largeNumber.

My suspicion is that Math.sqrt would be the fastest, as the javascript engine creators probably figured out the fastest way to calculate a square root.

Comment: Don't use dates to measure performance. Use `performance.now()`

Comment: Thanks, @Oriol, I changed my answer.

Comment: I tryed it for every function and i disocvered that sqrt performce better then the rest with running once, no matter what number. but when it is runned several times with the same number of different numbers in performce worse. I'll try to figure it out. tnx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As you could see here http://jsperf.com/sqrtvsasin `Math.sqrt` is way faster in its operations than `Math.asin`